# How to get non-image (plain) desktop background?

Tags: desktop-background

I don't want a background image on my desktop.  Even the color background is a PNG image file.  Want just a RGB color pick, or plain background.

Having a background image makes remote desktop too slow.

Ubuntu v19.04

Comment: This is a dupe of [No background options other than default pictures](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190066/no-background-options-other-than-default-pictures) and I left a comment there as to why GNOME removed the solid background color option.

Answer (score 17):

***this answer is targeted for RGB color option***

1. Get your present background picture with the below command

`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri`

Example:

```
pratap@i7:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/contest/bionic.xml'
pratap@i7:~$
```

2. Make the background picture to none with the below command

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri ''`

3. Now the background picture is none so the background will be the value of

`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color`

Example:

```
pratap@i7:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color
'#000000'
pratap@i7:~$
```

4. Set the desired rgb value for primary-color with the below command

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color 'rgb(255, 173, 100)'`

Example:

```
pratap@i7:~$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color 'rgb(255, 173, 100)'
pratap@i7:~$
```

other gsettings points to know

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background color-shading-type

gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background secondary-color
```

Alternatively you can use `dconf-editor` which can be installed with the below command

`sudo apt install dconf-editor`

[image]

Comment: Getting a warning on setting the picture to '' (second command)

failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=49c4cdfbcf4eb51283f46a37db743d09 --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1

Could it be because I'm rdp'ing into my desktop?

Comment: If you're using VNC or RDP to remote log in, this is a must!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options for selecting different backgrounds, including using a flat color:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/look-background.html.en

"You can Change the image used for your backgrounds or set it to be a solid color.

1. Open the *Activities* overview and start typing *Settings*.
2. Click on Settings.
3. Click Background in the sidebar to open the panel.
4. Select Background or Lock Screen.
5. There are three choices displayed on top:

• Select Wallpapers to use one of the many professional background images that ship with GNOME. Some wallpapers change throughout the day. These wallpapers have a small clock icon in the bottom-right corner.

• Select Pictures to use one of your own photos from your Pictures folder. Most photo management applications store photos there. If you would like to use an image that is not in your Pictures folder, either use Files by right-clicking on the image file and selecting Set as Wallpaper, or Image Viewer by opening the image file, clicking the menu button in the titlebar and selecting Set as Wallpaper.

***• Select Colors to just use a flat color.***

6. The settings are applied immediately.
7. Switch to an empty workspace to view your entire desktop."