# Set a desktop image, can't unset back to flat colour

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

In 20.04, I was trying out the desktop/background pictures and decided that I didn't like any of them.

There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to go back to "blank"?

I mean - I could create a flat black (my preference) in gimp and choose that as my background image - but surely resetting the desktop to "nothing but flat colour" shouldn't require that much work?

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri ''` should do the job.

Comment: if you want to set the color other than black.. run `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color blue` followed by above command.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1169145/739431

Comment: This is a dupe [No background options other than default pictures](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190066/no-background-options-other-than-default-pictures) and I left a comment there as to why GNOME removed the plain color background option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get non-image (plain) desktop background?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169145/how-to-get-non-image-plain-desktop-background)

Answer (score 1):

The capability is there just not through the Settings GUI.  This Ask Ubuntu [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169145/how-to-get-non-image-plain-desktop-background) provides details for setting the desktop background either with `gsettings` command or using `dconf-editor`.